# After resizing NAS box new size does not show up under df -h

Tags: fdisk, df

We have a 500GB NAS box attached to a Linux box and it appears as /dev/sdb. However after re-sizing from 345GB to 500GB the new size is not registering.

```
[root@localhost iscsi]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                      8.5G  982M  7.1G  13% /
tmpfs                 242M     0  242M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   55M  405M  12% /boot
/dev/sdb              345G  328G     0 100% /mnt/iscsi
```

For some reason lsblk shows the correct size but an old mount point. The correct mount point is /mnt/iscsi. An incorrect mount point appears in /proc/mounts also.

```
[root@localhost iscsi]# lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
sda                           8:0    0   10G  0 disk
├─sda1                        8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                        8:2    0  9.5G  0 part
  ├─VolGroup-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0  8.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─VolGroup-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  992M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                           8:16   0  500G  0 disk /mnt/iscsi/apple

cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=237476k,nr_inodes=59369,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root / ext4 rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/proc/bus/usb /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext4 rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdb /mnt/iscsi/apple ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdb /mnt/iscsi ext3 rw,relatime,errors=continue,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
[root@localhost iscsi]# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

Fdisk correctly recognizes the size of the NAS box.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65270 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Any suggestions how to proceed? /dev/sdb does not appear in pvdisplay, lvdisplay.
What I am confused about is that should /mnt/iscsi.. be mounted on a partition on /dev/sdb? 
Currently we are having to manually mount via `mount /dev/sdb /mnt/iscsi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resize it

```
resize2fs /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this will do exactly? I think /dev/sdb is the whole NAS box, will I lose data?

Comment: it pretty much tells the filesystem to use up to the new blocks you allocated to /dev/sdb. You will not lose data and can do it while mounted

Comment: One thing I don't understand though is how can we mount /mnt/iscsi to a whole HDD? Doesn't there have to be a partition?

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: fdisk /dev/sdb shows that there is no partition table, so I don't understand how the mount is working.

Comment: you don't need to create a partition to put a filesystem then mount a filesystem on a device. You can `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb` It will give you a warning but in the end work

Comment: Interesting, cheers.